# Evaluate $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}}(1-\frac 12 +\frac 13 - \frac 14 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to calculate this limit.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac 12 +\frac 13 - \frac 14 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}) $$
I tried to pair the terms of the sum in order to reduce each other but without any succes. By writing the sum:
$$\frac{1}{1*2} + \frac{1}{3*4}+\frac{1}{5*6}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}$$
I have not reached anything useful. Could you help me?

Comment: Hint: what's the Maclaurin expansion of $\ln(1+x)$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what Maclaurin expansion is ... I am studying math by myself and didn't encounter it so far

Comment: As you might be learning from the answers below, in general, calculating the value of infinite sums is not easy.  A few are e.g. $1 + \frac{1}{2}  + \frac{1}{4}  + \frac{1}{8}  + \frac{1}{16}  +\ldots$.  On the other hand, $1 - \frac{1}{3}  + \frac{1}{5}  - \frac{1}{7}  + \frac{1}{9}  +\ldots = \frac{\pi}{4}$ is not so simple.

Comment: Do you know how to integrate?
Consider that you limit actually means to sum infinite terms $1 -1/2+1/3+\ldots+1/n-1/(n-1)+\ldots$ and this is the same thing as calculate $$\int_2^{\infty } \frac{1}{n (n-1)} \, dn=\log (2)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Prove by induction that 
$$1-\frac 12 +\frac 13 - \frac 14 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$$

Then use the fact that $\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$ is a Riemann sum.

**Solution 2**
$$\begin{align}
u_n &=1-\frac 12 +\frac 13 - \frac 14 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\\&=1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 + \frac 14 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}-2 (\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2n})\\&=\left(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 + \frac 14 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n} -\ln (2n)\right)\\&\qquad-\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n)\right)+\ln(2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your post to use an aligned environment -- let me know if it looks alright.

Comment: @ClementC. Looks better, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

We can write the given sequence by

$$u_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$
Using that
$$\frac1k=\int_0^1 t^{k-1}dt$$
we get
$$u_n=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-t)^{k-1}dt=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{1+t}-\int_0^1\frac{(-t)^{2n}}{1+t}dt$$
The first integral in the RHS is $\ln 2$ and for the second integral

$$\left\vert\int_0^1\frac{(-t)^{2n}}{1+t}dt\right\vert\le \int_0^1t^{2n}dt=\frac1{2n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
Hence we can conclude that $\lim u_n=\ln 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.
$$
x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots=\int_0^x\left(1-t+t^2-t^3-t^4+\cdots\right)\,dt=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t}=\log(1+x)
$$
From this, one can obtain that
$$
1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots=\ln 2
$$

Comment: That is **not** obvious at all, is it? You're implicitly using [Abel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)... hiding or not mentioning that to the OP is bound to backfire at some point: one cannot do **anything** with power series without justification.

Comment: Abel's theorem is not necessary, as one can simply squeeze this one, as per user296113's answer

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt My point is -- it needs **justification**. Writing "From this, one can obtain that" as if it were obvious and trivial is at best misleading, at worst wrong. (And in this case, Yiorgos S. Smyrlis *is* implicitly using Abel's theorem. I am commenting on this answer, not user296113's.)

Comment: @ClementC.  Note that this answer begins with the word "Hint."  That means it's not intended to be a complete answer with all details.

Comment: I noticed. And I stand by what I wrote: if the OP has no clues about the subtleties of dealing with power sums, then how would they know based on this "hint"? Hence my first comment. Writing a "hint" is not a blank check: there are good and helpful hints, and some that can do more harm than good.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, Ramanujan made several contributions with these types of infinite series. More precisely, he used series of the form$$\varphi(a,n)=1+2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac 1{(ak)^3-ak}$$But that's enough of a history lesson.

---

Let's first perform a few manipulations to the summation at hand$$\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\frac {(-1)^{k+1}}k & =1-\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 14+\frac 15-\ldots+\frac 1{2n-1}-\frac 1{2n}\\ & =\left(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\ldots+\frac 1{2n}\right)-\left(\frac 22+\frac 24+\ldots+\frac 2{2n}\right)\\ & =\left(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\ldots+\frac 1{2n}\right)-\left(1+\frac 12+\ldots+\frac 1n\right)\\ & =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\frac 1k-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac 1k\end{align*}$$Now, we're ready. Using the definition of the Euler Mascheroni constant$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left\{\sum\limits_{k\leq x}\frac 1k-\log x\right\}=\gamma,$$we have$$\begin{align*}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\frac {(-1)^{k+1}}k\right\} & =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\frac 1k-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac 1k\right\}\\ & =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\frac 1k-\log 2n\right\}-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac 1k-\log n\right\}+\log2\\ & =\gamma-\gamma+\log2\\ & =\log2\end{align*}$$

P.S This was how Ramanujan found the limits of certain series in some of his early works. Other forms are$$\tfrac 43\log 2=1+\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\frac {2(-1)^k}{(3k)^3-3k}$$

Comment: Really nice presentation.

Comment: @A---B Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can write it as $S_n = (H_{2n}-\ln(2n))-(H_n-\ln n)+\ln2$ and use Mascheroni constant result. Here $H_n = 1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots + \dfrac{1}{n}$. Can you proceed?